# How do I display strings from an array vertically stacked?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, uilabel

I am trying to take each string in my array and list them in a label one string per line. I tried using the joined method with /n to attempt to make it got to the next line but it just literally puts /n in between each string. I'm sorry if this happens to be a duplicate but unless I'm wording my question wrong I cant seem to find an answer. This is an example of what I'm looking for.

```
String[0] 
String[1] 
String[2]
and so on...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let array = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]    
let string = array.joined(separator: "\n")
```

`joined` returns a new string by concatenating the elements of the sequence, adding the given separator (in this case, a line break) between each element in the array.

That will return this:

```
The
quick
brown
fox
```

...and set `yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

From Apple's documentation:

> The default value for this `numberOfLines` is 1. To remove any maximum
>   limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of
>   `numberOfLines` to 0.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the label can display multiple lines. If the `UILabel`  is named `lblText`, then:

```
lblText.numberOfLines = 0
```

Then, simply use string interpolation to add in the line feeds:

```
lblText.text = "\(String[0])\n\(String[1])\n\(Stribng[2])"
```

The issue might be that you used "/n" instead of "\n" :)